# How does the "Obsidian Ring of the Zodiac" work in Diablo 3?

Tags: diablo-iii

In Diablo 3, the legendary ring *[Obsidian Ring of the Zodiac](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/obsidian-ring-of-the-zodiac)* has the following legendary power since patch 2.2 ([patch notes](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/18642492/patch-220-now-live-4-7-2015#seasonalitems)):

> Reduce the remaining cooldown of one of your skills by 1 seconds when you hit with a resource-spending attack.

This can potentially allow for permanent uptime of certain skills (*Champion of Akarat, Wrath of the Berserker, Epiphany*, etc). However, it does not appear to scale as expected in situations with high density.

How does the ring's legendary power really work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The description is slightly misleading, as the cooldown reduction is only triggered on the *first hit* by each spender cast. This means a *multishot* or *blessed hammer* can only reduce a cooldown by **one second**, *no matter how many enemies are hit*.

The legendary effect does **not** appear to be affected by [proc coefficients](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Proc_Coefficient) ([source](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/17261347119), [source](https://www.reddit.com/r/Diablo/comments/34rbe7/zodiac_ring_uses_internal_cooldowns_or_proc/)), and conflicting reports are likely due to people expecting the ring to be able to reduce the cooldown every time a spender hits, not just the first (as per the first paragraph).

The cooldown that is reduced is **randomly** picked among your current remaining cooldowns ([source](https://www.reddit.com/r/Diablo/comments/3c9p8i/obsidian_ring_of_the_zodiac_how_does_it_work/)).

This leads to a few conclusions:

- As long as you're hitting at least **one** monster, further *increasing mob density will not help you reduce your cooldowns*.
- Attack speed translates directly to cooldown reduction provided enough resources are available (given that at least one monster is being hit). *The maximum cooldown achievable is directly tied to how many spenders you can put out in the given time frame*. If you have a skill on a 90s cooldown, with a 30s duration, you need to hit with *60* spenders during that 30s duration to sustain permanent uptime.
- If resources are abundant, casting extra spenders instead of letting present ones finish mobs can be beneficial (for example, casting a second *Blessed Hammer* to kill a mob that would otherwise die from a previously cast one).
- To efficiently reduce the cooldown of a specific skill, one should *avoid casting other cooldown-dependent skills unless necessary*. The other skills will "steal" some of the random reductions and may prevent you from reaching permanent uptime  on the specific skill.

All in all, a better (or at least more accurate) description could be:

> Reduce a *randomly chosen* remaining cooldown of one of your skills by 1 seconds *the first time* you hit with a resource-spending attack.

*Also note that it is triggered when hitting debris or breakable containers, which can be useful for fast-moving builds.*

Comment: Can confirm. I am a crusader hammerdin in season 4. Cubed the ring. Density does not matter, but I still use it as it really helps with cooldowns anyway.

Comment: Did you test this all yourself? If not, please provide sources, I'd like to read more and see more confirmation of the first-enemy-hit mechanic.

Comment: @pfayze I provided three separate sources in the answer. Two of them are testimonial sources from _reddit_ (my own experience seems to confirm what they say). The conclusions are just consequences from the statements made in these sources. I have played with the ring for quite a bit and haven't (yet) seen anything to contradict the statements made, although there may be additional mechanics built in (some of my friends seem convinced there is some hidden internal cooldown built in, but I haven't been able to confirm this).