# Can the “Obsidian Ring of the Zodiac” work on followers?

Tags: diablo-iii

From patch 2.4, the Obsidian Ring of the Zodiac has been improved with a legendary option

> Reduce the remaining cooldown of one of your skills by 1 second when
>   you hit with a resource-spending attack.

Do followers use resource-spending attack in order to 'proc' the option?

Relevant question : [How does the "Obsidian Ring of the Zodiac" work in Diablo 3?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/234205/how-does-the-obsidian-ring-of-the-zodiac-work-in-diablo-3)

[image: Obsidian Ring of the Zodiac -item description]

Comment: Hello and welcome to Arqade. Regarding your requested tags, I don't think they'd improve the question. We use tags to help people find questions they are experts at. I don't think anyone's an expert at _items_, _followers_ or _proc_.

Comment: Thanks for the improvement. How can we categorize or refine the topic of the question? All in a root tag named diablo-3 does not seem right to me.

Comment: That would propably be a topic for the Meta, if you want a good and varied answer. I personaly think that such refinements are OK to be in the question itself. As said, the tags are mostly for discoverability of questions. I don't think there are enough Diablo 3 questions so that we'd need to further start to subdevide them. And, as said previously, the other tags wouldn't be too useful on their own.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.

Followers do not have any resource to spend. Their abilities are purely cooldown-based.